# imap_search() with for() will not search for sender

Tags: php, email, imap

The loop (`$zeile[$i]`) will not be executed, when it is in the `imap_search()` function.

The syntax (`$inbox, 'FROM " ' . $zeile[$i] . ' " '`) is like a lot of examples I have found.
Outside of this codeblock it works well. 
But inside even the line on the bottom (`echo "@" .$zeile[$i]."<br>";`) will not show anything.
With a single var (`$test = "domain.de";`) it works though.

```
$test = "domain.de";
$zeile = file("blacklist.txt");
for ($i=0;$i < count($zeile); $i++) {
    $emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM " ' . $zeile[$i] . ' " ');
    if ($emails) {
        foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
            imap_setflag_full($inbox, $uid, "\\Seen", ST_UID);
            echo "@" .$zeile[$i]."<br>";
        }
    } // if emils
} //Dateischleife
imap_close($inbox, CL_EXPUNGE);
```

Comment: Check that `file("blacklist.txt");` returns something.

Comment: yes, "Outside of this codeblock it works well"

Comment: `$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM " ' . $zeile[$i] . ' " ');` -> you probably want `$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "' . $zeile[$i] . '"');` instead (no spaces around the value).

Comment: no, i tried every posibillity of spaces and quotation marks in the last hour

Comment: not shure that this is right and working, but it seems logically. Line 70: https://hotexamples.com/de/site/file?hash=0x3c2a22601e8dd5b93cedef72de5d83ba7b38c0b7a79cb369546e6bf5950d4dd3&fullName=EmailController.php&project=aanyun/PHP-Sample-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found the problem.
The first email address from the text file determines the number of $ mails and thus the number of loops of if ($ mails). After that, there is no turning back to the line above.